# How to get more screen lock options?

Tags: lock-screens, nexus-4

In my Nexus 4, I have the following screen lock options.

```
None
Slide
Face Unlock
Pattern
PIN
Password
```

How can I get options other than these for my lock screen? I prefer non-rooted ways to get this done.

(The option I prefer is what I have in my Jailbroken iPod Touch - [AndroidLock XT](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2011/12/androidlock-xt-jailbreak-app-brings-android-like-lock-screen-to-jailbroken-iphone.html) that allows me to use an unlock pattern with the nine points to create the pattern, invisible. But I don't mind any other interesting options available for a screen lock on android)

Comment: What others even are there? Are you looking for something specific?

Comment: The example I mentioned with my iPod touch, its slightly different from what comes with Nexus 4. Are you saying there aren't any options other than these?

Comment: Not that I've ever heard of. I doubt that lock methods could even be added as individual apps, but custom ROMs might have the possibilities.

Comment: I've never heard of such either -- but I think it could be possible, if the app registers as "device manager". Still, I don't know of any such app in this context.

Comment: Another example I can think of is the lock screen for a windows phone, swiping and image upwards. I'm looking for any options other than the default available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get a lock screen similar to the one available for Windows Phone,
   try [Lock Screen 7](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rout.lock.lockscreen7&hl=en).
2. [WidgetLocker Lockscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker&hl=en) is a paid app which promises to give more lock screen options.
3. [Quick Launch Social Lockscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.conduit.locker&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5jb25kdWl0LmxvY2tlciJd) is another option.
4. Then there's [Active lockscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.celltick.lockscreen&feature=search_result).
5. [Holo Locker Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobint.locker.plus&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5tb2JpbnQubG9ja2VyLnBsdXMiXQ..) and its [free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobint.locker&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5tb2JpbnQubG9ja2VyIl0.) version.

Comment: Feel free to add to this list if anybody finds more ways or options to change screen lock options.